# convert a theano tensor into a tensor of 0 and 1 based on a boolen condition

Tags: python, theano

I'm trying to transform a theano tensor into a tensor of 0 and one based on the values being  > 0. Is this the right way to do it?

```
tensor = tensor > 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the command `gt` (stands for greater than). It works as follows:

```
from theano import tensor as T
X = T.dvector('X')
f = theano.function([X],T.gt(X,0))
x = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
print x  # prints [4 0 5 9 5]
print f(x)  # prints [True False True True True]
```

Comment: as I just want another tensor, I think T.gt(X,0) should be sufficient right?

Comment: Yes. That is all you need. I used `theano.function` and the rest of the stuff to show you how it works.